# Clean install of ubuntu 18.04 LTS - struggling to set dns server manually

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

Please bear with me because I'm very new to using linux.

I'm trying to set my dns server on a clean install of ubuntu 18.04 but I can't seem to make it work. I just need to be able to ping my domain controller by hostname. Our dhcp server hands out a different dns than our primary domain controller so it must be set manually on devices (complex situation, has to be this way, don't ask) I:

1) installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and did updates with software updater

2) went into settings > network > ipv4 > turned off automatic dns > and then set my dns servers (first ip is my primary domain controller, second ip is my secondary domain controller)

3) disabled ipv6

4) rebooted

I can ping my domain controller by ip, but not by hostname. If I nslookup my domain controller by hostname, it resolves with the correct dns server. I've had no issues on other linux distros, or on windows machines or osx machines.

My /etc/hosts file is as follows

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.1.1 my-machines-hostname
```

Any ideas here? Thanks in advance. Apologies because this is a probably a dumb question with a dumb answer, but I've tried googling. :p

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just had to put my dns server in /etc/hosts

What does setting dns with gui even do then? Nothing?